Under what conditions are the remaining coefficients of a regression with a variable omitted "scaled" relative to those in the complete regression?
I was reading [this][1] article that discusses the impact of ommitting variable from a regression equation, and analyzes the impact it will have.
Here is some notation they use: given an $m \times n$ data matrix $X$, response variable $y$, we have the normal equations for the regression coefficients given by:
$$\widehat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$$
Now suppose we have ommitted some variable z. If we re-ran the regression with that variable included, we would have new regression coefficients $\beta, \gamma$, such that
$$y \sim X\beta + z\gamma$$
They then give the equation for the coefficients of the regression with the ommitted variable in terms of the coefficients of the complete regression:
$$\widehat{\beta} = (X'X)^{-1}X'y=(X'X)^{-1}X'(X\beta + z\gamma + \epsilon)$$
$$=(X'X)^{-1}X'X\beta +(X'X)^{-1}X'z\gamma + (X'X)^{-1}X'\epsilon $$
In my particular case, each of the regression variables in X is a random (uncorrelated) bernoulli variable taking values in $\{0,1\}$, so they all have the same mean and variance and no covariance.
I'm trying to use the kind of analysis above to understand the conditions under which the following is true: when we omit a variable, the remaining coefficients all simply get scaled proportionally, so that the predicted value when all of them are set to 1 remains the same as before.
In other words, let's say that we have the following value when all of the regression variables in the complete regression are set to 1 (i.e. the sum of all of the regression variables):
$$C=\mathbf{1'}\beta+\gamma$$
Under what conditions is it the case that $$\widehat{\beta} = \frac{\beta}{C-\gamma}?$$
My intuition is that this should be the case in my special case, and I'm trying to prove whether or not its true. the reason I think it should be true is that when you omit the variable, the prediction when all regression variables are set to 1 will be too low, and needs to be scaled up. Since all of the variables have the same variance and no correlation, I would think they should all be scaled up by the same amount proportionally.
Can someone help me prove this statement, or a different one that is similarly simple based on the constraints of my special case that is actually correct?
Unfortunately, from the above math, it seems that since each of the regressors in $X$ and $z$ are uncorrelated, $X'z=0$, and so there should be no expected "inflation" to the regression coefficients in the incomplete regression. But that doesn't seem correct...
Thank you,
Paul
EDIT:
After answering a similar question on this site I got some more intuition on this. My final comment above is only true when both $X$ and $z$ have zero mean. When that is not the case, the inner product $$E[x'z]=m\bar{x}\bar{z}$$.
Since all of the regressors are uncorrelated bernoulli variables, I know that $\bar{x}=\bar{z}= \frac{1}{2}, $ so $$E[x'z]=\frac{m}{4}$$
Furthermore, let's look at the term $(X'X)$ using the uncorrelated bernoulli assumption. For each diagonal element, $E[x'x] = nE[x_i]= \frac{m}{2},$ while for the off-diagonal elements, $E[x'y]=m\bar{x}\bar{y} = \frac{m}{4}$ so $$(X'X)=\frac{m}{4}I+\frac{m}{4}$$
While I don't have an expression for the closed form of this omitted variable bias, the above suggests that it should be identical for all of the regression coefficients. If that is the case (as opposed to my intuition that each coefficient should be inflated proportionally), I would expect the answer to be that each of them has an amount $\frac{\gamma}{n}$ added to it, so that the total when all regressors are 1 is still $$\mathbf{1'}\widehat{\beta}=\mathbf{1'}(\beta+\frac{\gamma}{n}\mathbf{1})=(C-\gamma)+\gamma=C.$$
However, I don't see how this would be the case, as the expressions I derived don't have any dependence on the number of variables, n. so I'm still not sure how to arrive at an intuitive answer to my question for this special case.
[1]: https://timeseriesreasoning.com/contents/omitted-variable-bias-in-linear-regression-models/#:~:text=Thus%2C%20when%20we%20omit%20a,(%CE%B2_cap_zX%7CX)%20term.
